# Compiling C program using GCC with GMP library error: "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"

Tags: c, macos, gcc, gmp

I'm trying to compile a C program (gfp2.c) that uses many functions from the GMP library. I downloaded and installed the GMP library using the normal configure, make and install sequence. I also ran make check before the install and there were no errors.

I am using GMP 5.1.1, GCC 4.2.1 and MAC OS 10.8.2.

I first type `gcc gfp2.c -lgmp` to link the library and then tried `gcc gfp2.c` and get the following output on the terminal:

```
1407-wn-172-21-30-223:pqcrypto11_scripts dfish$ gcc gfp2.c -lgmp 

v1407-wn-172-21-30-223:pqcrypto11_scripts dfish$ gcc gfp2.c

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "___gmp_printf", referenced from:
      _print_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmp_randinit_default", referenced from:
      _setup_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmp_sprintf", referenced from:
      _get_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_add", referenced from:
      _add_GF in ccrft0vq.o
      _mul_GF in ccrft0vq.o
      _sqr_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_add_ui", referenced from:
      _add_GF_ui in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_addmul", referenced from:
      _inv_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_clear", referenced from:
      _clear_GF in ccrft0vq.o
      _setup_GF in ccrft0vq.o
      _free_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_cmp", referenced from:
      _cmp_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_cmp_ui", referenced from:
      _is_one_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_fdiv_ui", referenced from:
      _setup_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_init", referenced from:
      _init_GF in ccrft0vq.o
      _setup_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_init_set_str", referenced from:
      _setup_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_init_set_ui", referenced from:
      _setup_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_invert", referenced from:
      _inv_GF in ccrft0vq.o
      _a24 in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_mod", referenced from:
      _add_GF in ccrft0vq.o
      _add_GF_ui in ccrft0vq.o
      _sub_GF in ccrft0vq.o
      _sub_GF_ui in ccrft0vq.o
      _scalar_GF in ccrft0vq.o
      _scalar_GF_si in ccrft0vq.o
      _mul_GF in ccrft0vq.o
      ...

  "___gmpz_mul", referenced from:
      _scalar_GF in ccrft0vq.o
      _mul_GF in ccrft0vq.o
      _sqr_GF in ccrft0vq.o
      _inv_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_mul_2exp", referenced from:
      _setup_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_mul_si", referenced from:
      _scalar_GF_si in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_neg", referenced from:
      _inv_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_pow_ui", referenced from:
      _setup_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_set", referenced from:
      _copy_GF in ccrft0vq.o
      _add_GF_ui in ccrft0vq.o
      _sub_GF_ui in ccrft0vq.o
      _neg_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_set_str", referenced from:
      _set_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_set_ui", referenced from:
      _shamir in ccrft0vq.o
      _a24 in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_sizeinbase", referenced from:
      _mont_3ladder in ccrft0vq.o
      _shamir in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_sub", referenced from:
      _sub_GF in ccrft0vq.o
      _neg_GF in ccrft0vq.o
      _mul_GF in ccrft0vq.o
      _sqr_GF in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_sub_ui", referenced from:
      _setup_GF in ccrft0vq.o
      _sub_GF_ui in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_tstbit", referenced from:
      _mont_3ladder in ccrft0vq.o
      _shamir in ccrft0vq.o

  "___gmpz_urandomm", referenced from:
      _random_GF in ccrft0vq.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm pretty new to C programming and using libraries, etc. and really do not know what I'm doing so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt has already done the compilation and the linking. You don't need to do the second step. If you check your directory you'll find a file called a.out that is the executable you need.

Answer (score 2):

You need to link in the GMP library:

```
gcc gfp2.c -lgmp
```

(it's not clear why you got that working initially and then re-ran without the library).